# Passing the selected id row in the first query to be used in the second query

Tags: javascript, php, mysql, sql

I have a table and it has a button where it would get the `ID` of the selected row in the first query :

```
echo "
<td>
    <a type='button' id='seemore' data-toggle='modal' idNum='".$row['marriage_id']."' 
      data-target='#see_more'> 
      </a> 
</td>";
```

The `idNum='".$row['marriage_id']."'` is equal to the `ID` number of that row. I want to use  `idNum='".$row['marriage_id']."'` in my second query as my `WHERE` clause.

This is what I currently have:

```
 SELECT * FROM marriage WHERE marriage_id = idNum
```

Comment: Can you post your script with queries you're trying?

Comment: @Sithu Sorry, I dont have a script. im just try to use the selected id from the table and pass it to my next query inside my modal. im using bootstrap

Comment: @KhielynYu Your question may not be answerable until your post your complete code flow or script.

Comment: Well, most likely you will want to pass the id to the server using XHR, but any attempt at that implementation is completely missing from your question ...

Comment: @Ja͢ck I agreed with you. And I don't understand why this kind of question was upvoted.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If i understood correctly, you want to access the value of ID which can be used as a parameter for DB query. You can learn more about my implementation in jQuery with this link [CreateEvent](http://api.jquery.com/category/events/event-object/)

You have mentioned that, on button click, you are getting the **'ID'** of the selected row

> "..it has a button where it would get the ID of the selected row in the first query"

And you want this ID to be appended as

> SELECT * FROM marriage WHERE marriage_id = ID

as a DB query to some server, then Add below line of codes in the event listener of button click:

```
//event listener for button clicked
$('#btn').on('click', function(e){
    //var id;
    //Your logic to get the ID of the selected row and assign it to variable id 
    var e = $.Event( "build" );
    //Trigger the custom event along with the id as data to be passed
    $(this).trigger(e,[id] );
});
```

Now only thing left for you is to add a listener for the custom event generated, i.e. 'build'. Add that listener to the table (assuming its id-- 'tbl') and follow this:

```
 $('#tbl').on('build', function(e, param){
    //param is the ID of the selected row. In here you can perform XHR providing ID as parameter
     //alert(param);
 });
```

Hope that helps to resolve the problem you are facing now!